# How do i make my program move on to the next elif in python

Tags: python, if-statement

```
import random
print"hello what is your name?"
name = raw_input()
print"hello", name
print"wanna play a game? y, n"
choice = raw_input()
if choice =='y':
    print'good lets start a number guessing game'

elif choice =='n':
    print'maybe next time'
    exit()

random.randint(1,10)
number = random.randint(1,10)
print'pick a number between 1-10'
numberofguesses = 0
guess = input()

while numberofguesses < 10:
 if guess < number:
    print"too low"
 elif guess > number:
        print"too high"
 elif guess == number:
        print'your correct the number is', number
 break
if guess == number:
    print'CONGRATS YOU WIN THE GAME'
```

when i enter my guess into the program it only gives me one output for example
i enter 8
programs output is "too high"
but when i guess again the output is blank, how do i fix this?
            hello what is your name?

```
 ed
    hello ed
    wanna play a game? y, n
    y
    good lets start a number guessing game
    pick a number between 1-10
    2
    too low
    >>> 5
    5
    >>> 3
    3
    >>> 2
    2
    >>>
```

Comment: Show your input and output. Your description of your problem is inscrutable. http://sscce.org/

Comment: @EdwardLaPiere: those `>>>`you are seeing means that you are no longer inside your program. Those numbers are being evaluated by the interpreter and simply being spit back. (Your program terminates because your `break` is in the wrong place, as the below comments mention).

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you want:

```
numberofguesses = 0

while numberofguesses < 10:
 guess = input()  #int(raw_input("Pick a number between 1 and 10: ")) would be much better here.
 numberofguesses+=1
 if guess < number:
    print "too low"
 elif guess > number:
    print "too high"
 elif guess == number:
    print 'your correct the number is', number
    break
```

With your version of the code, you guess once.  If you're wrong, your program tries the same guess over and over again forever (assuming your `break` was actually supposed to be indented in the `elif`).  You might be typing new guesses into the terminal, but your program never sees them.  If the `break` was actually in the correct place in your code, then you guess once and whether write or wrong it exits the loop right away.

Comment: @Marcin -- I moved the guessing into the while loop.  I also increment the number of guesses and put the break in the right place.

Answer (score 2):

your break is outside of your ifstatement

It will execute while loop one time and break no matter what